# How to use Java ENUMs with an interface?

Tags: java, enums

I want to use an Enum in Java for storing configuration values for different environments. Each Enum will have the same fields, but different values. Something like:

```
public enum DevelopmentConfig
{
   URL("..."),
   defaultURL(".....");
}

public enum ProductionConfig
{
   URL("..."),
   defaultURL(".....");
}
```

This is for a web application, so I can't simply use `Preferences` or any other solution.

My question is, is there a way to create an interface to define the fields of the configuration? Or should I be using a normal `class` instead of `enum` for storing these values?

Edit: To use this, I simply want to do this from my other classes:

```
String url = Config.URL
```

Or

```
String url = Config.getURL();
```

Without knowing if that refers to `Config.Development` or `Config.Production` (I want that to be determined in the Config enum's constructor itself and have it choose the right set of fields)

Comment: Enums can implement interfaces, if that's what you're asking.

Comment: Can you, please, show us how are you going to use this? Enum constants are static. Do you want to pass a class somewhere?

Comment: @defaultlocale I've edited it to add some more details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each member of the enum is an instance of the enum class.  That means that you can define methods, variables and implement interfaces:

```
public interface Config {
    String getKey();
}

public enum DevelopmentConfig implements Config
{
    URL("url"),
    DEFAULT_URL("defaulturl");

    private String key;

    private DevelopmentConfig(String key){
        this.key = key;
    }

    public String getKey(){
        return this.key;
    }
}
```

If you're looking to use enums to look-up values, I would recommend using them as a key in a Map instead of implementing different types per need.

**Edit**

You can accomplish this by reading in a .property file from a location in the environment your application is running in (dev / prod / etc), then keying into the property file with the enum:

```
//This has reads in a property file:
PropertyManager propertyManager = new PropertyManager(/*prop file location*/);

String url = propertyManager.getConfig(DevelopmentConfig.URL);
```

PropertyManager's API would look like the following:

```
PropertyManager {
    String getConfig(Config config);
}
```

Comment: What I'm trying to do is have two sets of configuration values, both with the same fields and different values. Then from my other classes, I simply want to use `Config.URL` without knowing whether it refers to `Config.DEV.URL` or `Config.PRODUCTION.URL`. What would you suggest for this?

Comment: I have actually done exactly this with pairing enums with the Properties read from a .property file.

Comment: Problem with that is, I won't have autocomplete for the fields in Netbeans which is what I want. Can you tell me how can I accomplish this via enums or regular classes?

Comment: The enums, propertyManager and configurations will all autocomplete.  Im not sure what you are looking for.

Comment: i think i'm quite clear in describing what I want.. I've even added some code examples in my edit to the question

Answer (score 9):

You're misusing enums.

Each enum member can be implemented as an anonymous class that overrides things:

```
public enum Config {
    DEVELOPMENT {
        @Override
        ...
    },
    PRODUCTION {
        @Override 
        ...
    };

    public abstract ...;
}
```

Comment: what's the use of defining everything as a class when I simply want to store one string or int value. Should I use a regular class instead?

Comment: I think a regular class would be better, as there I could also specify the data type of the fields. What would you suggest?

Comment: @ClickUpvote: You should store all of the configuration settings as methods or final fields in the enum.

Comment: @ClickUpvote: Exactly what I just wrote.  Make an abstract `url()` method.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use enum in the following manner. With this you can store(and retrieve) different values for each Config

```
    public enum Config{
        DEVELOPMENT("DEV_URL", "DEV_DEFAULT_URL"), 
        PRODUCTION("PROD_URL", "PROD_DEFAULT_URL");

    private String url;

    private String defaultURL;

    Config( String url, String defaultURL )
    {
        setUrl(url);
        setDefaultURL(defaultURL);
    }

    public String getUrl()
    {
        return url;
    }

    public String getDefaultURL()
    {
        return defaultURL;
    }

    public void setDefaultURL( String defaultURL )
    {
        this.defaultURL = defaultURL;
    }

    public void setUrl( String url )
    {
        this.url = url;
    }
}
```

Comment: That's not bad but if I have to add a 100 configuration options later, I will need to supply a 100 arguments via the constructor.

Comment: @ClickUpvote: That's why you should user overridden abstract methods instead.